# Convert a string into a JSON object

Tags: c#, json, string

I work with the microsoft translator API and try to convert the answer into a JSON object to get the detected language.

This is the answer string

```
"[{\"language\":\"de\",\"score\":1.0,\"isTranslationSupported\":true,\"isTransliterationSupported\":false,\"alternatives\":[{\"language\":\"nl\",\"score\":1.0,\"isTranslationSupported\":true,\"isTransliterationSupported\":false},{\"language\":\"en\",\"score\":1.0,\"isTranslationSupported\":true,\"isTransliterationSupported\":false}]}]"
```

I need the first "language":"de"

I allready tried to convert with Newtonsoft JObject.Parse() but it doenst work

This is how the string looks like if printed to console:

```
[{"detectedLanguage":{"language":"de","score":0.8},"translations":[{"text":"Hallo Mein Name ist Danny","to":"de"},{"text":"Ciao il mio nome è Danny","to":"it"}]}]
```

And this ist the error printed by JObject.Parse(string);

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1.
```

EDIT:

This is the HTTPRequest the JSON string comes from:

```
   string TranslateText(string text)
{
    string host = "https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com";
    string route = "/translate?api-version=3.0&to=de&to=it";
    string subscriptionKey = COGNITIVE_SERVICES_KEY;

    System.Object[] body = new System.Object[] { new { Text = @text } };
    var requestBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body);

    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage())
    {
        // Set the method to POST
        request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
        // Construct the full URI
        request.RequestUri = new Uri(host + route);
        // Add the serialized JSON object to your request
        request.Content = new StringContent(requestBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        // Add the authorization header
        request.Headers.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey);
        // Send request, get response
        var response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
        var jsonResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        // Print the response
        return jsonResponse;
    }
}
```

And then I try to work with the response:

```
string json = TranslateText(text);

JArray jArray = JArray.Parse(json);

string firstLanguage = jArray[0]["language"].ToString();
```

The Response Is a valid json, because if I write the response into the code it works, but it seems like I need to wait till the request response assigned its result.

Comment: "I already tried to convert with Newtonsoft JObject.Parse() but the quoting is wrong." what does it mean?

Comment: what is error message as a result of doing `JObject.Parse()`

Comment: It looks like you can replace `“` and `”` with regular quote char `"` and then use JsonConvert

Comment: Those look like fancy/angled quotes which aren't gonna be valid json

Comment: the fancy quotes were my fault, edited the original string

Comment: And are those backslashes *actually* in the JSON, or is this just what you're seeing in the debugger? (What do you see if you print it to the console?)

Comment: You can't use `JObject.Parse` for this because the root here is an array, not an object, as evident by the `[...]` root. You can use `JToken.Parse`, but you might just as well use `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` as Marco has shown in his answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost close with `JObject`,

But your json is not an object, its a Array of object so you need `JArray` to parse it successfully.

1) Parse it to `JArray`

2) By querying on `JArray` you can get first language by using index 0.

```
string json = @"[{""detectedLanguage"":{""language"":""de"",""score"":0.8},""translations"":[{""text"":""Hallo Mein Name ist Danny"",""to"":""de""},{""text"":""Ciao il mio nome è Danny"",""to"":""it""}]}]";

JArray jArray = JArray.Parse(json);

string firstLanguage = jArray[0]["detectedLanguage"]["language"].ToString();
```

**Output:** (From Debugger)

[image]

Comment: This should work fine thank you.
Just have to fix that my json string is a return of a method sending a HTTP Post, so I need to wait for the result because the string is null otherwise.

Comment: Ok,  but what **wait** actually mean here => *so I need to wait for the result because the string is null otherwise*. Does you mean async await?

Comment: If I "jArray = JArray.Parse(jsonString);" I always get a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."-Error. But the json string is there because I can print it before..

Comment: you please copy my code as it is on new class file. and let me know if it work or not **OR** let me know how you integrate my code at your end.

Comment: I Integrated your code, but I dont assign the json string via hard code, because I get the json as a response of a httpRequestMessage.

If I assign the json string like you it works.

Comment: oh, then please add your response `httpRequestMessage` code to your post so I'll take a look on it

Comment: Could you please show me how your `jsonResponse` look by adding breakpoint and debugging.

Comment: I printed it out and it is the exact string you used in your answer

Comment: Oh, i think I got it whats the issue is. Let me know which json did you receive in `jsonResponse` because in your post there is 2 different jsons and I used 1st one and might be your `HttpRequestMessage` returns you 2nd json

Comment: Oh.. yeah.. Its the 2nd one.. Sorry :D

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. 
I will try to improve my questions next time.

Comment: If answer help you then mark the tick on left side of answer to make it green and upvote by clicking up arrow :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the [JsonConvert.Deserialize](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Overload_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject.htm) method to deserialize.

Since you are trying to deserialize into a JObject it won't deserialize directly, as your JSON string contains an array, hence convert it first to a `List<JObject>` then do a `.FirstOrDefault()` to find out the `language` property's value.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string data = "[{\"language\":\"de\",\"score\":1.0,\"isTranslationSupported\":true,\"isTransliterationSupported\":false,\"alternatives\":[{\"language\":\"nl\",\"score\":1.0,\"isTranslationSupported\":true,\"isTransliterationSupported\":false},{\"language\":\"en\",\"score\":1.0,\"isTranslationSupported\":true,\"isTransliterationSupported\":false}]}]";

        List<JObject> deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<JObject>>(data);

        string languageCode = deserializedObject.FirstOrDefault()["language"]?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;

        Console.WriteLine(languageCode);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
string str = "[{\"language\":\"de\",\"score\":1.0,\"isTranslationSupported\":true,\"isTransliterationSupported\":false,\"alternatives\":[{\"language\":\"nl\",\"score\":1.0,\"isTranslationSupported\":true,\"isTransliterationSupported\":false},{\"language\":\"en\",\"score\":1.0,\"isTranslationSupported\":true,\"isTransliterationSupported\":false}]}]";

dynamic arr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(str);

string language = arr[0].language;
```

Language value:

> "de"